# Spring data jpa default schema for native query in repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-dat-jpa in Spring Boot Application and trying to execute a native query in repository. It works fine when I append schema name with table name but it does not work independently and won't pick the schema name from application.properties file as it does for Entity classes I defined

I am using below property to set default schema it works fine for entity classes and Named queries. But when I write any native query in @query it starts complaining about schema name:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=NPS_WO
```

Below is my query:

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TypeRef,Long> {


    @Query(value="SELECT t.* from Type_Ref t")
    public List<Object[]> findAllTypes();

}
```

In my actual scenario this query will be replaced by a complex native query.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please ensure `SELECT t.* from Type_Ref t` is actually a valid query ? I think it should be `SELECT * from Type_Ref t` instead.

Comment: I corrected the query but still its asking me for Schema name

Comment: It is not needed this query. JpaRepository has inherit (from CrudRepository) method findAll which works as you expect in this query. -->TestRepository.findAll(). http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--

Comment: I have added this query as an example , actually i have a requirement where query is very complex and have joins with so many tables. what should i do in that case

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: No i have used the approach of adding schema name in Jdbc url and as we have only one schema in database , so never thought of alternative. it would be great if you have any other approach

Answer (score 29):

You can access the default schema name within native queries by using `{h-schema}`.

So your query should look like that:

```
@Query(value="SELECT t.* from {h-schema}Type_Ref t")
public List<Object[]> findAllTypes();
```

There is no dot between the h-schema and the table name, this is added automatically.

Comment: This works good for single scheme. What would be the case for multiple schema?

Comment: This should be flag as answer. Since we talk about "default" schema, there should exist only one.